# How to interpret LED driver output labels?

Tags: led, led-driver, constant-current

I am looking to drive an LED panel with an alternative driver to better suit my application, but first need to understand the existing one which does not seem to match the same labelling convention as others on the market.

The LED panel is a full white-spectrum device and the driver is a constant current type with output labels 'CW-', '+', and 'CC-'. Can anyone clarify the function of each of these outputs and their electrical/signal characteristics?

[image: LED Driver]

Comment: A a guess: Constant Current (-), Constant Wattage (-), (+).  Use only one or the other (-) along with the (+) output.  That said: might be best to look up the datasheet for the module.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no industry standard for the labelling of the output terminals on LED drivers (I work for a large lighting manufacturer and we're not even consistent across our own product lines). This is a question for the manufacturer of that driver, and should be answered by their published datasheet.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a tunable color temperature device. CW is cathode, warm. CC is cathode, cold. Plus is the anode.